# How to get mp3 file details from remote folder file using php?

Tags: php

I want to know how to get mp3 file details like artist, title, album etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at getID3 : http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

There is a PECL extension and a PEAR package for ID3 tags:

- http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php
- http://pear.php.net/package/MP3_IDv2

For getting the files out of the folder, have a look around SO, as it has been covered multiple times. You likely want to [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) all MP3 files. Or use a [`DirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) in case you want to check by MimeType instead of extension.